# Angular Material (any version) label or placeholder not floating

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm facing really annyoing issue for quite a long time.

I've upgrade my angular from version 6 to the newest one (currently 9.1.3, material 9.2.1).

The problem is:
the label and/or placeholder is not floating. It happens only when I open the application in browser for the first time after ng serve. The bug dissapears when i refresh browser tab.
[not floating placeholder bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abORS.png)

the code look like this:

```
<div class="field__wrapper">
  <p>Location</p>
  <mat-form-field class="form__field">
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        placeholder="E.g. Santorini, Greece"
        formControlName="location"
        maxlength="60">
    <mat-error *ngIf="newEventForm.controls['location'].touched && !newEventForm.controls['location'].dirty">
      Location is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you move your label inside the mat-form-field and place it inside a <mat-label> tag.

Comment: it doesnt help. the same thing happens. I'm using bootstrap too. maybe there is friction between angular material and boostrap?

Comment: No it doesn't. I use both of these together and they don't conflict. Could you pick up an sample from angular material website and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Try reproducing the issue on stackblitz - that will give us something to work with.